# WebScraping - Site com opções de escolhas

Tags: r, rvest

tenho uma pergunta mais genérica (embora esse site seja mais apropriado para coisas mais específicas), e agradeceria se alguém puder ajudar com algumas dicas de por onde começar.

É possível fazer scraping em um site que tenha caixas de opções, como esse?

https://filia-consulta.tse.jus.br/#/principal/download
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho conhecimento básico do `rvest` e sei como pegar dados simples como esse:

```
partidos <- "http://www.tse.jus.br/partidos/partidos-politicos/registrados-no-tse"

partidos <- partidos %>%
read_html() %>%
html_table() %>%
.[[1]]
```

Mas, não tenho ideia de como fazer a raspagem dos dados em links como o indicado acima. O problema é que não consigo encontrar o(s) link(s) de onde estão armazenados os dados que aparecem para download ao clicar em "consultar". Alguém tem alguma dica ou sugere algum material para eu pesquisar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um ponto de partida para se conhecer o funcionamento de qualquer site são as ferramentas para desenvolvedor disponíveis nos navegadores. Neste caso, eu utilizei a aba Network (Rede) do Chrome para verificar de onde o arquivo estava sendo baixado:

[image: Aba network das Ferramentas de Desnvolvedor exibindo a requisição para o arquivo baixado]

Daí percebi que ao selecionar o PT do Espírito Santo, por exemplo, o navegador fez uma requisição para a URL:

http://agencia.tse.jus.br/estatistica/sead/eleitorado/filiados/uf/filiados_pt_es.zip

Você pode perceber um padrão aí. Mas argumento que, mais importante do que resolver o seu caso específico, é aprender a utilizar bem as ferramentas de desenvolvimento disponíveis nos próprios navegadores, para isso recomendo os materiais abaixo:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools

No futuro, quando quiser lidar com sites assim, você pode utilizar ferramentas como o [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) para automatizar operações:

> Esses pacotes não são suficientes para acessar todo tipo de conteúdo
> da web. Um exemplo claro disso são páginas em que o conteúdo é
> produzido por javascript, o que acontece em muitos sites modernos.
> Para trabalhar com esses sites, é necessário realmente “simular” um
> navegador que acessa a página web. Uma das melhores ferramentas para
> isso é o selenium. Não discutiremos selenium nesse curso, mas caso
> queira se aprofundar, acesse aqui. [2](http://material.curso-r.com/scrape/)

Comment: Muito obrigado, felubra. Agora consegui encontrar os links. E ótimas dicas, vou pesquisar sobre elas com tempo. Por ora, agora conseguirei baixar os dados no site do tse. Super valeu!